# Timestamp in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, weather

I am trying to extract data from a netcdf file using wrf-python. The data is for every hour. The date is being extracted as a number, and not a calendar-date-time. First I extract the data, convert it to a flat np array, then try to save the file. The format is saved as '%s'

```
np.savetxt((stn + 'WRF_T2_T10_WS_WD.csv'), np.transpose(arr2D), %s, delimiter=',', header=headers, comments='')
```

it looks like this: [image: it looks like this]

but it needs to look like this: [image: but it needs to look like this]

Thanks

Comment: Like this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623156/how-to-convert-the-integer-date-format-into-yyyymmdd

Answer (score 5):

By convention, dates are frequently stored as an [offset in seconds from Jan 1, 1970](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Encoding_time_as_a_number)

For the case of converting seconds, this answer [Python Numpy Loadtxt - Convert unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31339046/python-numpy-loadtxt-convert-unix-timestamp) suggests converting them by changing their datatype (should be as efficient as possible as it dodges by-row loops, copying data, etc.)

```py
x = np.asarray(x, dtype='datetime64[s]')
```

However, the `E+18` postfix implies that if you really have a date, your timestamps are in nanoseconds, so `datetime64[ns]` may work for you

```py
import time
import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([time.time() * 10**9])  # epoch seconds to ns
>>> a  # example array
array([1.60473147e+18])
>>> a = np.asarray(a, dtype='datetime64[ns]')
>>> a
array(['2020-11-07T06:44:29.714103040'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly and is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @AlyceSalaTenna Excellent, thanks! If this solved your problem, please mark this as the Answer with the check to its left!