# pandas to_datetime not working with numpy where

Tags: python, pandas

I have a date column that's of string/object type:

```
     Day - 2022  Day - 2021  ...
0    01/01/2022  01/01/2021  ...
1    02/01/2022  02/01/2021  ...
2    03/01/2022  03/01/2021  ...
3    04/01/2022  04/01/2021  ...
4    05/01/2022  05/01/2021  ...
..          ...         ...  ...
725  27/12/2023         NaN  ...
726  28/12/2023         NaN  ...
727  29/12/2023         NaN  ...
728  30/12/2023         NaN  ...
729  31/12/2023         NaN  ...
```

I can cast to date no problem like so:

```
pd.to_datetime(df["Day - 2022"])
0     2022-01-01
1     2022-02-01
2     2022-03-01
3     2022-04-01
4     2022-05-01
         ...    
725   2023-12-27
726   2023-12-28
727   2023-12-29
728   2023-12-30
729   2023-12-31
Name: Day - 2022, Length: 730, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

But when I use `np.where` to detect whether a string column is in fact a date in string format it returns big integer instead:

```py
col = "Day - 2022"
pattern = "^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{2,4}"
df[col] = np.where(
     df[col].str.match(pattern),
     pd.to_datetime(df[col]),
     df[col],
)
```

```
              Day - 2022  Day - 2021  ... 
0    1640995200000000000  01/01/2021  ... 
1    1643673600000000000  02/01/2021  ... 
2    1646092800000000000  03/01/2021  ... 
3    1648771200000000000  04/01/2021  ... 
4    1651363200000000000  05/01/2021  ... 
..                   ...         ...  ... 
725  1703635200000000000         NaN  ... 
726  1703721600000000000         NaN  ... 
727  1703808000000000000         NaN  ... 
728  1703894400000000000         NaN  ... 
729  1703980800000000000         NaN  ...
```

Confused as to why this is happening? Any ideas on how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Seems like a timestamp in nanoseconds, try to play around with pd.to_datetime() parameters (unit, origin,...)

Comment: No idea but it seems to be converting the string into UNIX time format so just change it to `pd.to_datetime(df[col],unit='ns')` or using `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1640995200000000000 * 10e-10)`

Comment: The reason is `df[col]` is of object type and by default, the use in np.where of either a datetime type (from `pd.to_datetime(df[col])`) or an object type (from `df[col]`) will result in an array of object type. I understand that in your example, the `df[col]` is never really possible in the `np.where`, but the casting to object of the result is probably done before. Try yourself that the result is the same if you cast to object `pd.to_datetime(df["Day - 2022"]).to_numpy().astype('object')`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```py
col = "Day - 2022"
pattern = "^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{2,4}"
df[col] = np.where(
     df[col].str.match(pattern),
     np.asarray(
        df[col].astype(np.datetime64),
        dtype="datetime64[s]",
     ),
     df[col],
)
```

So the `np.where` was converting the date strings into a numpy array of unix timestamps, thereafter used answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31339264/9372996) to convert the array into datetime types.